# Как изменить регистр буквы в значении строки?

Tags: java

Существует строка со значением `down_to` ,  на выходе необходимо получит значение `down_To`. Как это можно прописать?

Comment: `toUpperCase()` остальное сами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "when_the_light_goes_dark";
    String result = "";
    result = result + str.substring(0, 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ("_".equals(str.substring(i-1, i)))
            result = result + str.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase();
        else
            result = result + str.substring(i, i+1);
    }

    System.out.println(result);


 //output: when_The_Light_Goes_Dark
```

Comment: Меееееееееедленно...

Comment: @Qwertiy с каких пор линейный алгоритм является медленным?

Comment: С тех пор, как из-за сложения строк он стал квадратичным. StringBuilsder надо было использовать, а то и вообще массив. А ещё вместо `substring` в проверке можно делать `charAt`.

Comment: @Qwertiy насчет сложения строк согласен, моя вина

Answer (score 0):

```
class Upper{
    /*
    Метод перевода в верхний регистр всех
    символов заданной строки в промежутке
    от start до end
    */  
    String upString(String str, int start, int end){
        StringBuffer ourString = new StringBuffer(str);
        // При неправильно заданном промежутке сработает
        // исключение и сообщит об ошибке в индексах
    try{
        // изменяемая на верхний регистр подстрока
        String substr = ourString.substring(start,end).toUpperCase();
        // непосредственно замена в заданной строке
        ourString.replace(start, end, substr);                      
    }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        return "Index error";
    }
    return new String(ourString);       
    }
}
public class Primer{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String oldstroka = "down_to";
        String newstroka;
        Upper upper = new Upper();
        newstroka = upper.upString(oldstroka, 5, 6);        
        System.out.println(newstroka);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. для каждой новой строки придётся переписывать код? А перед этим посчитать на какой позиции находится нужный символ, а то и не один.

Comment: Ну это же просто для примера смотря какое задание. Конечно, можно написать методы интерактивного ввода исходной строки, позиций начала и конца промежутка для изменения т.д. Но было бы больше кода. Здесь же показан принцип, а не полноценное приложение. А иначе можно и до GUI добраться )))

Comment: А вообще в вопросе четко не поставлена задача: изменять регистр символа, следующего за символом нижнего подчеркивания либо второго символа от конца строки (предпоследнего)?